# Mocking Jenkins class for unit testing

Tags: jenkins, mocking, jenkins-plugins, powermock, jenkins-groovy

I have written a class for cancelling a build of a particular job based on build number.

Now I am not understanding how to mock Jenkins related stuffs for my unit tests

This is the class

/**
 * Cancel the builds of a particular job
 */

```
import jenkins.model.*

def call(Map options = [:]) {
if(!options.job)
    error "Parameter job (jenkins job path) is missing"
if(!options.numbers)
    error "Parameter numbers (build numbers) is missing"
def numbers = options.numbers instanceof List ? (options.numbers?.flatten() as Set):options.numbers

for(def number:numbers) {     
    echo "Cancelling the job $options.job with build number $number"
    abortBuild(options.job, number)
}

}

def abortBuild(String job, Integer number) {
def build = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(job)
        .getBuildByNumber(number)
if(null != build && build.isBuilding() || build.isInQueue()) {
    build.finish(hudson.model.Result.ABORTED, new java.io.IOException("Aborting build"))
}
}

return this
```

Test class which I tried  was wrapping this class

```
   class WrapCancelBuilds extends BasePipelineTest {
   List<String> messagePublished = []
   String errorMessage


  def run( def jobName, def numbers ) {
  super.setUp()

  def script = loadScript('vars/cancelBuilds.groovy')
  helper.registerAllowedMethod(method('echo', String.class), { message ->
     messagePublished.add(message)
  })
  helper.registerAllowedMethod(method('error', String.class), { message ->
     errorMessage = message
  })
  helper.registerAllowedMethod(method('abortBuild', String.class, int), {
    true
  })     
  script([job:jobName,numbers:numbers])

  }
```

I get following error message
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getItemByFullName() on null object

How to resolve it